# Как после выполнения return метод продолжает работать?

Tags: java

Есть метод который ходит в `DB` и вытаскивает клиента из таблицы. Происходит странная аномалия, в дебагере после прохождения строки `return result;` метод переходит к строке `} catch (Exception e) {` и не заходя в тело `catch` (Специально поставил ловить все типы `Exception`) снова выполняет строку `return result;` после чего выходит из метода.

Не подскажите в чем может быть причина такого поведения?

```
public Client getClientById(final int id) {

    try (final PreparedStatement statement =

                 connection.prepareStatement(

                         scripts.get("get_client"))) {

        statement.setInt(1, id);

        final ResultSet set = statement.executeQuery();

        if (set.next()) {

            final Client result = new Client();

            result.setId(id);
            result.setName(set.getString("name"));
            result.setLogin(set.getString("login"));
            result.setPassword(set.getString("password"));
            result.setEmail(set.getString("email"));
            result.setCreate(set.getTimestamp("create_date"));
            result.setRoleId(set.getInt("role"));
            result.setAddress(new Address(set.getInt("address")));

            return result;
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return new Client();
}
```

Comment: Мне кажется, что дело в try-with-resources, и таким образом дебаггер показывает закрытие соединения с базой.

Comment: @diraria да точно вы правы. Попробовал в похожем месте то же самое. Спасибо.